# Azure Web Role wont start when child folder has files with long paths

Tags: git, azure, asp.net-web-api, filepath

A bit of very remote help and a bit of a lingering question.

For the last few days I have struggled with a very frustrating Azure Web Role issue. Essentially my workflow is as follows:

1. Create a brand new Azure Cloud Service project
2. Add a C# ASP.NET Web Role (Web API)
3. Build and confirm that the project will start locally

You should be good to here. Where my wrinkle always appeared was when I cloned a Git repo into the Web API project directory (the repo houses a simple UI development server in node and all the compiled UI assets). It took me a bit to put together, but essentially, some of the nested node dependencies had file paths that were too long (dependencies had dependencies had dependencies etc) and hung the Web Role.

If you want to try it yourself you might include a folder in the Web API project that has files with long paths, or build a simple git repo and use npm to install some packages. My package.json for the UI repo follows:

```
{
  "name": "BreaksMyHeart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Wont let the web role start",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "co-views": "^0.3.0",
    "flux": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.0.0",
    "jade": "^1.9.2",
    "koa": "^0.18.1",
    "koa-compress": "^1.0.8",
    "koa-route": "^2.4.0",
    "koa-static": "^1.4.9",
    "object-assign": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "browserify": "^9.0.4",
    "coffee-reactify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-batch": "^1.0.5",
    "gulp-coffee-react-transform": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-coffeelint": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-react": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.4",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.0.0",
    "koa-logger": "^1.2.2",
    "merge-stream": "^0.1.7",
    "mocha": "^2.2.4",
    "supertest": "^0.15.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "vinyl-transform": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Mike",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

To be clear, I was not including the node_modules directory in the project, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

The Azure Compute Emulator will warn you that roles are taking longer than usual to start. Feel free to keep waiting, I lost patience after 10 minutes or so (on a development machine with i7 and 16G ram).

To resolve the issue, try deleting the folder. You might find that it is not a simple task, as file paths are too long; a naive

```
rmdir UIRepo
```

from the command prompt will not suffice and you'll need to try something like this https://superuser.com/questions/256105/how-do-i-delete-a-folder-which-is-nested-quite-deep-and-avoid-file-name-too-lon

Can anyone else confirm? I have worked around the issue by putting the UI repo elsewhere and repointing gulp build tasks appropriately.

Comment: Thanks berserker, I like this solution and will give it a try. Managing two source controls can be tiresome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite common problem with node_modules, because of 260 characters path length limitation on Windows. When this is exceeded programs accessing these long paths will have problems as you mentioned.
To get rid of long paths you might consider using [shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap):

```
npm shrinkwrap
```

This generates `npm-shrinkwrap.json` based on your current node_modules structure which will be used to drive further instalations of package dependencies without nesting (if not really required, because of different versions).

> The shrinkwrap command has locked down the dependencies based on
>   what's currently installed in node_modules. When npm install installs
>   a package with an npm-shrinkwrap.json in the package root, the
>   shrinkwrap file (rather than package.json files) completely drives the
>   installation of that package and all of its dependencies (recursively)